# Defining constructor with defaults. Am I doing this right?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am quite new to javascript an trying to make sense of the basics. Coming from Python I am a bit overwhelmed by the different ways to get stuff done.

I came up with the pattern below to make constructors. I hope this is sound practice: is it? Some specific questions remain:

- I jump to doing `_this = this` right away and only use `_this`. Is there any harm in that?
- I allow the constructor to take an object as the first argument. The object properties become 'named parameters' and overwrite defaults. Any disadvantages to this?

Sorry that my questions aren't very specific, but I need a bit of confirmation/criticism at this stage.

```
var Omelette = function () {
    var _this = this;
    _this.publicName = 'Dexter';
    _this.publicEggs = 6;

    // Override property values with custom supplied values
    // This comes after the default values and before they are used
    for (var p in arguments[0]) {
        _this[p] = arguments[0][p];
    }

    var privateGreeting = 'Hello, ';

    _this.publicSayHi = function () {
        console.log(privateGreeting + _this.publicName );
    };

    var privateBreakEggs = function (brokenEggs) {
        _this.publicEggs = _this.publicEggs - brokenEggs;
    };

    // initializing the prototype breaks two eggs
    privateBreakEggs(2);

    console.log(_this.publicEggs);
};

var myOmelette = new Omelette({
     publicName: 'Roy'
});
// 4

var hisOmelette = new Omelette({
     publicEggs: 12
});
// 10

hisOmelette.publicSayHi();
// Hello Dexter

hisOmelette.publicEggs = 12;
// No more eggs are broken
console.log(myOmelette.publicEggs);
// These are unchanged

hisOmelette.breakEggs();
// not publicly accessible. error 'undefined is not a function'
```

Comment: "only use _this. Is there any harm in that?" - it's slow and silly. You also don't put your methods on the prototype which is slow and harder to reason about. Also -  why all the private stuff silliness? Why are you using `arguments` instead of passing a parameter to the constructor? Also, your defaults approach could just be an `Object.assign` or better yet - not at all : you can let the user set those. The bigger issue is that questions this specific should probably be asked at codereview.stackexchange.com and not on stackoverflow

Comment: That bad huh? If I understand you correctly, using `_this` unnecessarily 'copies' my methods to the object. The `arguments` approach seemed like a convenient way to handle defaults and use named parameters... Thanks for taking the time here.

Comment: I agree with @BenjaminGruenbaum about the `_this`. Why introduce a private var here. You should just use the `this` keyword throughout your `construct`. However you can't reach the private functions anymore with `hisOmelette` en `myOmelette`. And of course *omelette du fromage* *omelette du fromage* *omelette du fromage* *omelette du fromage* *omelette du fromage* *omelette du fromage* *omelette du fromage* *omelette du fromage*

Comment: I was under the impression that using `var` inside the constructor was a common way to keep your properties and method protected from changing. I admit that my example is silly, but in general it should be ok?

Comment: @RoyPrins, nothing that isn't inside the function scope could change the variables. However functions inside the function scope can!

Comment: We can debate this in the JavaScript chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript or you can open a question on codereview. I don't think the comment section in a StackOverflow question is a good place for discussion - it is used for clarification requests etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following code:

```js
 var Omelette = function (overrideObject) {
  this.publicName = 'Dexter';
  this.publicEggs = 6;

  // Override property values with custom supplied values
  if (overrideObject)
  {
   var keys = Object.keys(overrideObject); //get all the keys from the override object.
                        //We use Object.keys for this. -> puts all the keys of an object into an array.
   for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i)
   {
    this[keys[i]] = overrideObject[keys[i]]; //loop over every key and overwrite/set the value a public variable.
   }
  }

  var privateGreeting = 'Hello, ';

  this.publicSayHi = function () {
   console.log(privateGreeting + this.publicName ); //this refers to the instance created and the owner of function publicSayHi.
  };

  var privateBreakEggs = function (brokenEggs) {
   this.publicEggs = this.publicEggs - brokenEggs;
  };
  
  this.breakEggs = privateBreakEggs; //reference to privateBreakEggs, making it publically available.
 
  //this won't work since the this in privateBreakEggs refers to its own scope.
  privateBreakEggs(2);
  
  //this will work since it's called via `this`.
  this.breakEggs(2);

 };

 var myOmelette = new Omelette({
   publicName: 'Roy'
 });
 myOmelette.publicSayHi(); //should say Roy.

 var hisOmelette = new Omelette({
   publicEggs: 12
 });
 hisOmelette.publicSayHi(); //should say Dexter

 console.log(hisOmelette.publicEggs); //10
 console.log(myOmelette.publicEggs); //4
 // These are unchanged

 hisOmelette.breakEggs(2); //eggs now 8
 console.log(hisOmelette.publicEggs)
 
 hisOmelette.privateBreakEggs
 // not publicly accessible. 'undefined'
```

I've made several changes to your code and commented. Compare it with your own code and learn from the differences. I'm no longer introducing the `_this` variable, since it's unnecessary.

There are no real disadvantages to override the default properties of an instance using an argument. The could be added to the instance after it's created, now they are added during creation. Your method (improved by me) allows for easy creation of properties on the creation of the instance. Bear in mind that the properties are only set on that instance. If you want them to be shared with all the instances use a prototype.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will digest it in the morning, but it certainly addressed some of the issues. I wonder why you were downvoted (and nobody bothered to leave a comment).